# ArcGIS Search searching only in my own toolboxes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, search-window

when I want to search for some tool and I write e.g. Merge into Search window (ctrl+F), ArcGIS (ArcMap) finds only tools named Merge or similar that are located in my own toolboxes. It doesn´t find normal ESRI installed Merge located somewhere in... management toolbox I think. Why? It just searches through my own toolboxes and not ESRI installed toolboxes.

If I delete search index in options, it is ok then (it finds all Merge tools - default and also mine) but just for a while. Then something unnoticable happens and search is corrupted again.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?
Thanks
jonlew

Win8 64bit, ArcGIS for Desktop - Basic 10.1 SP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found a temporary solution. I added a path to standard ArcGIS toolboxex in Search options - tab Index - window Registered folders and server connections. The truth is that now it finds a tool I need twice (1 for default search and 1 for folders I manually added) but it´s better than none like before.
It is not an ideal solution but it works.